# Comparing types in lists

Tags: c#, types, unity-game-engine

I asked a similar question to this over on Unity3D Q&A, but I didn't get a response. I've finally got back round to this project and still have the same issue.

[Link To Unity Question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/689816/checking-for-multiple-components-on-a-gameobject.html)

I have searched, but I don't think I've hit the right keywords cause I still haven't found an answer that fits. Anyway, I will ask the question a different way and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

So below is the code that I have come up with, it's not the actual code in the game, but it does a good job at showing my problem.

Basically, in the build() method I want to check that both lists each contain the same type of tool, without actually hard coding the type. I don't care about the specific tool instance, just that it is of a certain type. The aim is that I can create new tools without having to modify the build method to incorporate these new types.

If there is a better way to do it I'm all ears.

Thanks

```
namespace TypeExample
{
    class Tool
    {

    }

    class Spanner : Tool
    {

    }

    class Wrench : Tool
    {

    }

    class Builder
    {
        List<Tool> toolsAvailable = new List<Tool>();

        List<Tool> toolsRequired = new List<Tool>();

        public Builder()
        {
            Spanner spanner = new Spanner();
            Wrench wrench = new Wrench();

            toolsRequired.Add(spanner);
            toolsRequired.Add(wrench);
        }

        public void GiveTool(Tool tool)
        {
            toolsAvailable.Add(tool);
        }

        public void build()
        {
            // if true

            Console.WriteLine("Building");

            // else

            Console.WriteLine("I don't have the tools to build!");

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Spanner spanner = new Spanner();
            Wrench wrench = new Wrench();

            Builder builder = new Builder();

            builder.GiveTool(spanner);
            builder.GiveTool(wrench);

            builder.build();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you should get all the types from collections using [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) and then compair the result.

```
var toolsAvailableTypes = toolsAvailable.Select(t => t.GetType()).Distinct();
var toolsRequiredTypes = toolsRequired.Select(t => t.GetType()).Distinct();
if (toolsRequiredTypes.Except(toolsAvailableTypes).Any())
{
    //building
}
```

It is not clear, should you compair only types of instruments or quantity also. My answer assume you don't care about quantity and you can build with one `spanner` when you require two.

**-Update**

To comply the requirement about subclasses (Sriram Sakthivel mentioned it) you can check if available tool type is subclass to required tool type so you can use any `SpecialSpanner` when you need a `Spanner`

```
var toolsAvailableTypes = toolsAvailable.Select(t => t.GetType()).Distinct().ToList();
var toolsRequiredTypes = toolsRequired.Select(t => t.GetType()).Distinct().ToList();

if (CanBuild(toolsAvailableTypes, toolsRequiredTypes))
{
    Console.WriteLine("building");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not enough minerals");
}
```

`CanBuild` method:

```
bool CanBuild(List<Type> toolsAvailableTypes, List<Type> toolsRequiredTypes)
{
    foreach (var requiredType in toolsRequiredTypes)
    {
        bool isAvailable = toolsAvailableTypes.Any(availableType => availableType.IsSubclassOf(requiredType) || availableType == requiredType);
        if (!isAvailable)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but `Count() == 0` can be optimized by `!Any`

Comment: I did not include it in the code for simplicity, but I have checks to ensure that only 1 type of each tool can be added to the list. Sorry, I didn't know that it might effect the answer.

Comment: Thanks, At the moment I don't need it, but it is good to know. I'd up vote if I could. Thanks again.

Comment: I actually ended up using this answer, it was my fault down to missing out some key details in the question, but I did actually have subclasses in the game code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reqdTypes = toolsRequired.Select(x => x.GetType());
var availableTypes = toolsAvailable.Select(x => x.GetType());

if (reqdTypes.Except(availableTypes).Any())
{
    //Something exist in reqdTypes which is not in availableTypes
}
```

Note:This will fail if you provide more derived type than expected type. For example if you provide `SpecialSpanner` in place or `Spanner` this won't work.